# C# implementation of T-SQL round function

Tags: c#, t-sql, rounding

I'm trying to reproduce in C# the behavior of the [T-SQL Round function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) when a truncate function is used.

This is the SQL behavior I'm trying to reproduce in C#:

```
SELECT ROUND(150.757,2,0) -- 150.76
SELECT ROUND(150.757,2,1) -- 150.75

SELECT ROUND(150.747,2,0) -- 150.75
SELECT ROUND(150.747,2,1) -- 150.74
```

In `System.Math` there are two methods that I tried to use.

The first one, `Math.Truncate` truncates to the whole part only, so it won't help me.

The other method is `Math.Round`.

This method has 2 interesting overloads.

```
Math.Round(decimal,int)
Math.Round(decimal,int,System.MidpointRounding)
```

The MidpointRounding enumeration options are:

```
System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
// When a number is halfway between two others, 
// it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero.

System.MidpointRounding.ToEven
// When a number is halfway between two others,
// it is rounded toward the nearest even number.
```

Executing the two overloads of `Math.Round` with the same data as SQL I've got the following result:

```
Math.Round(150.757, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // 150.76
Math.Round(150.757, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) // 150.76

Math.Round(150.747, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // 150.75
Math.Round(150.747, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) // 150.75
```

Given that none of the MidpointRounding solve my problem, what is the best way to reproducte the T-SQL function in C#?

**Update:**

After implementing Paul's answer I noticed one extra odd behavior from T-SQL ROUND function:

```
SELECT ROUND(150.747,-2,1) // 100
SELECT ROUND(150.747,-2) // 200
```

I edited Paul's answer to include support for this edge case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine somebody will come up with a better way, but this is certainly a possible way!

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(150.757.TruncateWithDecimalPlaces(2));
        Console.WriteLine(150.747.TruncateWithDecimalPlaces(2));
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static double TruncateWithDecimalPlaces(this double input, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        double factor = Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
        return Math.Truncate(input*factor)/factor;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
150.75
150.74
```

A more complete implementation would look something like this:

```
public static double Round(double input, int decimalPlaces, int roundType = 0)
{
    double factor = Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    if (roundType == 0)
    {
        if (decimalPlaces >= 0)
        {
            return Math.Round(input, decimalPlaces);
        }
        return Math.Round(input * factor) / factor;
    }
    return Math.Truncate(input * factor) / factor;
}
```

Comment: I'd even throw an exception if decimalPlaces < 0; Round(150.757, -2, 1) returns 100 ;-)

Comment: @odalet, Hmm, i think i misread your comment first time! T-SQL's ROUND function supports a negative number of decimal places so i included that.

Comment: I updated the question with one extra edge case of the T-SQL Round Function.

Answer (score 2):

I've elaborated a bit on Paul's answer so that his method provides the same behavior as TSQL's round (btw I didn't make my version an extension method):

```
    using System;

    namespace TestTSql
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(TSqlRound(150.757, 2, false));    // 150.76
                Console.WriteLine(TSqlRound(150.757, 2, true));     // 150.75
                Console.WriteLine(TSqlRound(150.747, 2, false));    // 150.75
                Console.WriteLine(TSqlRound(150.747, 2, true));     // 150.74
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public static double TSqlRound(double input, int length, bool truncate = false)
            {
                if (truncate)
                {
                    double factor = Math.Pow(10, length);
                    return Math.Truncate(input * factor) / factor;
                }
                else return Math.Round(input, length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `TSqlRound(150.757, -2, false)` throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which is consistent with `Math.Round` but not with T-SQL's ROUND function. I guess that would be up to the implementer to decide.

Comment: Indeed, but Pedro's request was to reproduce TSQL behavior. So your solution remains the best one.